# Hash Tree (Merkle Tree) error localization question for 128 data blocks

Tags: hash, cryptography, hashtable, merkle-tree, hashtree

For a hash tree that covers 128 data blocks, how many hash checks do you need to perform to localize the error? Assume that error occurred on only one block.

Comment: Please add more detail on this, like referral links, documentation, etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better asked on crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 15. 128 data block produce a tree of depth 8. To find the localize the error (2 multiply depth-1)=(2 multiply 8-1)=15